# Jumpy CSS transition in sidebar links text while toggle transition is running

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

When collapsing, the text adapts to the width of the sidebar progressively which causes a jumpy transition

I would like to know if there is any mechanism to show the text only when it fits 100% in the sidebar and it is not cut in two lines.

I need is the text to appear only after the transition of the collapse has finished.

What I've tried:

-Increasing/decreasing the transition time (too radical, works if I delete the transition but somehow has to be smooth so it's not a valid solution)

```
.sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 290px;
    background: #193D4C;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

-Using `backface-visibility` property. Did not work.

-Using Bootstrap 5 event type `shown.bs.collapse` like this:

```
var myCollapsible = document.getElementById('sidebar')
myCollapsible.addEventListener('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  alert("it works!"); //This never gets fired
})
```

I've been looking for a similar question for a long time but I didn't find anything

Comment: I would not animate `width`. It manipulates with layout (cumulative layout shift + browser has to recalculate layout) and [width is not very efficient in animation](https://pqina.nl/blog/animating-width-and-height-without-the-squish-effect/). I would rather think about `transform` with something like `translateX()`.

Comment: @Jax-p Sounds promising, could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

add the following CSS class to the text element:

```
.dont-break {
  min-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

example https://jsfiddle.net/Lnqpcujm/5/